# Magento httpd permissions issues

Tags: apache, magento2, file-permissions, centos7, httpd.conf

I am trying to install magento2 on a CentOS server. I am continuously getting permissions issue, the magento diretory is owned by apache and I set permissions to 777 (i know it is bad but just to test) but I still get permissions denied on file write. the path to magento dir is /var/www/html. I set permissions to /var/www/ and all sub-folders to 777 and file owner to apache still same.
also

> egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (returns)
>
> User apache
>
> Group apache

any suggestions or ideas, please?

Kind Regards

Sajid

Comment: provide more info. how did you set permissions? show parts of .bash_history for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following steps

```
sudo /usr/sbin/groupadd wwwrun
sudo  usermod -g wwwrun test
cd /var/www/html/magento2 && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && sudo chown -R apache:apache . && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

where test is the current logged-in user and then restart the http server.